# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I got this

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

when I tried to go to `http:/localhost/api/v1`

But I declare my `routes.php` already. See here

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
    Route::resource('url', 'UrlController');
});
```

and my `filters.php` look like this

```
Route::filter('api', function() {

    // Fetch a user record based on UN + PW     
    $user = User::where('username', '=', Input::get('username'))
    ->where('password', '=', Input::get('password'))
                ->take(1)
                ->get();

    if ($user->count() > 0) {
        Auth::onceUsingId($user[0]->id); // Authorize the user for this one request
    } else {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }});
```

My `index` function in my `Controller` look like this

```
<?php

class UrlController extends \BaseController {

    public function index(){
        return Response::json(User::all());
    }
}
```

It should show a list json file. I am not sure why it does that ? 
Can someone help me point out what I did wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you declared your route you would need to go to `/api/v1/url` to get to the `index` action.

You could either use that URL or change your routes like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
    Route::resource('/', 'UrlController');
});
```

Comment: I added `dd($user);` in my `filters.php`. How comes it doesn't work ? and instead it skip right into my index function and load all the json file. `public function index(){
  return Response::json(User::all());
 }`

Comment: Ehm your filter is called `api` and you register `auth.basic` as before filter. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes. Exactly right again. How do I fix that ? should I move the `api` on top of my auth.basic ? Will it make any diff ?

Comment: If you want to execute both filters you can do `'before' => 'auth.basic|api'` or `'before' => array('auth.basic', 'api')`

Comment: I like the | one better. :)

Comment: You're a lifesaver. You know that ? :) You're awesome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67341/discussion-between-iggy-and-lukasgeiter).